# How can i map the output from a service to an Object with specific values in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http, angular-pipe

I have a working function that maps the output of a service call to an object and then these to an Array.

The response from the API is like:

```
[
  {
     "paper_id": "0015023cc",
     "metadata": { }
     "abstract": []
     ...
  }
  {
     "paper_id": "0015023cc",
     "metadata": { }
     "abstract": []
     ...
  }
]
```

```
papersList(): Observable<Paper[]> {
        const url = `${this.allPapersUrl}/`;
        return this.http
            .get(url)
            .pipe(
            map((data: any[]) =>
                data.map(
                    (item: any) =>
                        new Paper(item.paperId, item.metadata, item.paperAbstract)
                    )
                )
            );
    }
```

How can i write a function for another service that returns the same object instead of an array?

The output from the API for the new service will be:

```
{
  "paper_id": "0015023cc",
  "metadata": { }
  "abstract": []
  ...
}
```

Code i'm trying to complete..

```
fetchPaper(pvalue: string): Observable<Paper> {
    const url = `${this.paperDetailUrl}`;
    params.append('paperid', pvalue);
    const url = `${this.paperDetailUrl}`;

    return this.http
             .get(url, {params: params})
             .pipe( ???
```

Comment: It seems like you're using a different url for `fetchPaper`, could you add the response you're supposed to get to the question?

Comment: Yes, it's another service call. Updated the question @SrThompson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to loop then. Also note you are getting `abstract` in the response and not 
`paperAbstract`

```
 return this.http
                 .get(url, {params: params})
                 .pipe(map(data:any => new Paper(data.paperId, data.metadata, data.abstract) ) )
```

Comment: Shows this..`Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
    src/app/services/papers.service.ts(39,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'data'.`

Comment: updated ans. Also do you have imported map ? `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm learning.. yes i have 'map' in imports. Got it to work.. `(data:any)` missing from your answer. `return this.http
                 .get(url, {params: params})
                 .pipe(map((data: any) => new Paper(data.paperId, data.metadata, data.abstract) ) );`

Comment: you can accept the answer if it helped. just a note if it is single argument  just `data` with out any in es6 syntax we don't  need brackets

Answer (score 1):

same operator map()

```
return this.http
  .get(url, { params })
  .pipe(
    tap(console.log),
    map(({ paperId, metadata, abstract }) => new Paper(paperId, metadata, abstract)),
  );
```

Comment: Shows for all 3.. `ERROR in src/app/services/papers.service.ts(40,14): error TS2339: Property 'paperId' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

Comment: give the console output

Comment: Thanks, the page works. With "tap(console.log)", i do not see compile errors. Without it, seeing this `    
    ERROR in src/app/services/papers.service.ts(44,15): error TS2339: Property 'paperId' does not exist on type 'Object'.
    src/app/services/papers.service.ts(44,24): error TS2339: Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'Object'.
    src/app/services/papers.service.ts(44,34): error TS2339: Property 'paperAbstract' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

Comment: I changed paperAbstract into abstract